# Numpy Summation for Index in Boolean Array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, boolean-logic

In Numpy I have a boolean array of equal length of a matrix. I want to run a calculation on the matrix elements that correspond to the boolean array. How do I do this?

```
a: [true, false, true]
b: [[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3]]
```

Say the function was to sum the elements of the sub arrays

index 0 is `True`: thus I add 3 to the summation (Starts at zero)

index 1 is `False`: thus summation remains at 3

index 2 is `True`: thus I add 9 to the summation for a total of 12

How do I do this (the boolean and summation part; I don't need how to add up each individual sub array)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use your boolean array `a` to index into the rows of `b`, then take the sum of the resulting `(2, 3)` array:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([True, False, True])
b = np.array([[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3]])

# index rows of b where a is True (i.e. the first and third row of b)
print(b[a])
# [[1 1 1]
#  [3 3 3]]

# take the sum over all elements in these rows
print(b[a].sum())
# 12
```

It sounds like you would benefit from reading [the numpy documentation on array indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html).